# How do I add a private repo from my organization to BuildHive?

Tags: cloudbees, buildhive

I'd like to add a private Github repo for my organization to BuildHive but for some reason they aren't showing in the "Add Projects from GitHub!" page.

Is there someway to add these or are private repos not yet supported? Is there some paid subscription service for BuildHive I can use to get this support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BuildHive is an intentionally simple build service: only open-source (or at least public) repositories supported, only on GitHub, and with minimal configuration options. If you want any other options, you can subscribe to the [DEV@cloud](http://www.cloudbees.com/dev.cb) service to get a Jenkins instance that you can configure however you like, including access to password-protected version control.